# Internal leaderboard for Python game

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

First of all, I'm still relatively new to programming, so please go easy on me.

I'm programming an arcade-like game with Python2.7 and I want to implement a leaderboard that can store, say, 10 pairs of username and score achieved. To give you an idea, it should look more or less like this:

```
1. AAA 100
2. BBB 10
3. CCC 1
```

...And so on. This way, it should be able to keep track of 10 scores.

When a player finishes the game and tops a score on the leaderboard, he should be prompted to enter a name with a maximum of 15 characters and the score should be saved. Furthermore, the code for the game should allow the player to look at the leaderboard **from the start menu**, i.e. the highscores should be possible to visualize upon clicking on "Leaderboard".

I've tried searching for a way to do this, but unfortunately the results either covered online leaderboards, only saved the highest ever reached score or were too complicated for me as a programming beginner to grasp. I also can't be sure whether any of those possiblities would allow for reading of the leaderboard in the game itself.

I'd much appreciate if someone could lend me a hand with this issue.

(In case I wasn't clear enough (I was tired when writing this), my only problem is opening and reading from/writing to a different file containing the leaderboard and displaying it in the game. I do not, however, want it to appear in the Shell.)

Edit:

```
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
readfile = open("leaderboard.txt", "r")
text = font.render(readfile, True, (27,100,225))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

As suggested I tried the render command, and so far I've come up with this, but I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "L:\game.py", line 97, in <module>
text = font.render(open("leaderboard.txt", "r"), True, (27,100,225))
TypeError: text must be a string or unicode
```

Comment: You need to break this down into smaller problems and research and attempt each one individually - keeping track of the score during the game, prompting for user input, saving the user/score to a file, reading the file and sorting by score... as it stands this is a very broad problem (the only valid answer would be a full program written for you) and SO is for *specific* questions about *specific* programming problems.

Comment: One option--store it as a text file, read it in whenever a score is made, save each score/name in an array, insert the new score, then re-save the text file.

Comment: @Ant P Well, my only problem is actually the storing and reading of scores in a different file, as well as deleting them when they become superfluous. I can easily enough keep track of the score, with a variable and prompt the player to enter a name; I only wanted to explain the working of the game in case it was necessary. I just lack knowledge of how to keep track of those scores and then read them from the game file. I found a lot of results for reading files with Python but I didn't find anything about reading it while in the game.

Comment: @Louis That sounds like roughly what I was thinking of, but how to do it while in the game?

Comment: If your game is just a python program, the solution you have found will work anywhere in the program - it doesn't matter when you call it, so long as you can display the data clearly on screen.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I've understood now how to write and read files from the program, but the problem with that is that the leaderboard is then printed in the Shell, but I want it to be printed on the game screen. (I used print file.read() but maybe I need to use a different command?)

Comment: @MMM - in pygame I think you will need to build a surface, render the text onto it, and then place that surface onto the display.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Surface for displaying images? I don't seem to find anything on how to display text with pygame.Surface, only images ([Source](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html))

Comment: @MM - look at the pygame font module : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font - specifically the render method - I have now made this an answer.

Comment: In the posted code, you need to read the data in the file into strings and pass that to render - exactly as the error says - you can only pass in text or unicode strings, whereas you are trying to pass in a in a file object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a surface - and then use the [pygame.font Module](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font) - and specifically the render() method to draw text onto the surface.

Then place the surface onto the display as usual.

Comment: This looks helpful! I'll try this out as soon as I can and post about the results.

Comment: I've actually used render() on other places in the code so I feel a bit stupid now... in any case, now that I've tried doing that with a different file read from the code, it doesn't seem to work. Please tell me where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Without seeing your code - I have no idea. So long as you have the data in variables and they are valid strings, then it should work - but I haven't used pygame for a while, so I might not be able to help with your code.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I used, I just forgot to mention it in the comment, sorry

Comment: In the code you have posted you are trying to render a file, rather than reading the data from the file - using read or maybe readlines, and then trying to render that data.

Comment: Well, I am a programming noob - I don't really know what works and what doesn't. As for trying to render the data I'm afraid I can't figure it out. Using print in a new line would just return the data to the shell, while using font.render(readfile.readlines()[...]) returns the same error. Whatever I'm doing wrong, I don't think I'm making it better.

Comment: readlines() will read the whole file into a list - with one item in the list for each line in the file - and you can't pass that into render. You will then need to iterate around that list to render each line separately. You will also change the y co-ordinate of each line so that the lines don't overlap. There is a method on pygame.font library to work out the height of the rendered text so you know how much space to leave.

Comment: I'm starting to think I won't really able to get my head around this anymore, also this is becoming a bit long. I've tried doing more research now as well but didn't find anything I could understand and would be useful here. If you think you can at least attempt to write a code for reading the file I'd be very grateful. And thanks for all the patience you already showed to have with me.

Comment: It is a long time since I have written any pygame programs, and my concern is that my writing style would not fit well with your program. However if you would like to email me with your code, I can have a look if you want.

Comment: I would indeed like to email my code to you. I don't think your writing style would be that big of a problem, because unlike other programming languages I can actually get my formatting right in pygame most of the time. Just.. how to swap emails now?

Comment: click on my name in any of the above comments - my email is on the profile.

Comment: I wish that much would have worked. However, your email is only visible to yourself in your profile and I don't even think it's possible to change that here.

Comment: I've got a better idea, actually: pastebin. [Here](http://pastebin.com/EA9Lw7rL) is the code. The rest isn't complete yet either though, I'm still working on it. The leaderboard is supposed to be shown at `if game==1` and overwritten at `if game==6` - speaking of which I'd actually also enjoy help with the last section if it's not a problem for you. Thanks!

Comment: @MM read your pastebin please - I have left you a message - your code needs a lot of work.

Comment: You left me a message there? But I don't even have an account there, probably I can't actually read it...